# Stripe Checkout Undefined variable: response

Tags: stripe-payments

Im integrating the simple prebuilt checkout example from Stripe Docs (https://stripe.com/docs/checkout/integration-builder). But I get this error

```
Undefined variable: response in ../create-checkout-session.php on line 28
```

My html;

```
<script src="https://polyfill.io/v3/polyfill.min.js?version=3.52.1&features=fetch"></script>
<script src="https://js.stripe.com/v3/"></script>
<form action="/create-checkout-session.php" method="POST">
<button type="submit">Checkout</button> 
</form>
```

My create-checkout-session.php is the same code from the Doc.

The `var_dump` is working and it does have a ["url"] in it and when I open the URL manually its working.

```
    <?php
    require_once('../classes/stripe-php-7.87.0/init.php');
    \Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey('sk_test_...');
    header('Content-Type: application/json');
    $YOUR_DOMAIN = 'https://example.com/';
    $checkout_session = \Stripe\Checkout\Session::create([
      'payment_method_types' => ['card'],
      'line_items' => [[
        'price_data' => [
          'currency' => 'usd',
          'unit_amount' => 2000,
          'product_data' => [
            'name' => 'Stubborn Attachments',
            'images' => ["https://i.imgur.com/EHyR2nP.png"],
          ],
        ],
        'quantity' => 1,
      ]],
      'mode' => 'payment',
      'success_url' => $YOUR_DOMAIN . '/success.html',
      'cancel_url' => $YOUR_DOMAIN . '/cancel.html',
    ]);
    var_dump($checkout_session);
    return $response->withHeader('Location', $checkout_session->url)->withStatus(303);
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Same error here. I already included autoload.php.
Finally sorted out that this script is for Slim Framework.
Last line, use this:

```html
header('Location:'.$checkout_session->url,true,303);
```

Comment: Yeh, redirecting on your own is a good idea, but I don't know if its recommended.

Comment: Slim Framework is doing the same thing by using $response->withHeader('Location', $checkout_session->url)->withStatus(303);

Answer (score 1):

Use Composer version of stripe and include autoload file on the top as per the document. And it should be working fine.

```
require 'vendor/autoload.php';
```